Can't replace useragent
I use fake_useragent for a random user agent but it still remains python-requests/2.28.1
user = UserAgent()

header = {'user_agent': user.random}

link = "url"
responce = requests.get(link, headers = header).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(responce, 'lxml')
block = soup.find('div', id = 'tool_padding')

check_js = block.find('div', id = "javascript_check")
check_flash = block.find('div', id = "flash_version")
check_ua = block.find('div', id = "user_agent").text

result_js = check_js.find_all('span')[1].text
result_flash = check_flash.find_all('span')[1].text

print(f'js: {result_js}\nflash: {result_flash}\n', check_ua)

version updated to 1.5.1

isn't is supposed to be user-agent, with a hyphen, not an underscore?

You are using the incorrect key in your headers dictionary. The correct key for setting the User-Agent is "User-Agent" (hyphen + capital letters), not "user_agent" ;)

Changed header to headers
Changed 'user_agent' to 'User-Agent'
responce should be response

Try this:


from fake_useragent import UserAgent
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

user = UserAgent()

headers = {'User-Agent': user.random}

link = "url"  # Replace with your actual URL
response = requests.get(link, headers=headers).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'lxml')
block = soup.find('div', id='tool_padding')

check_js = block.find('div', id="javascript_check")
check_flash = block.find('div', id="flash_version")
check_ua = block.find('div', id="user_agent").text

result_js = check_js.find_all('span')[1].text
result_flash = check_flash.find_all('span')[1].text

print(f'js: {result_js}\nflash: {result_flash}\n{check_ua}')



